# Exchange sending QUIT after 220 ESMTP Status Ready

Tags: exchange, smtp, exchange-2010

I am hoping someone can help with an issue we are experiencing between our smart host and our Exchange 2010 Server.

When our smart host tries to deliver email to our exchange, we are met with a 451 Could not verify recipients - all MX Servers are unavailable for domain [Domain.tld].

I have researched this issue but all I can find online advises that the smart host were unable to make a successful connection.

When we investigate the SMTP Receive logs we see the following lines:

```
*,SMTPSubmit SMTPAcceptAnyRecipient SMTPAcceptAnySender  SMTPAcceptAuthoritativeDomainSender AcceptRoutingHeaders,Set Session  Permissions
>,"220 [Domain.tld] Microsoft ESMTP MAIL Service ready at Sat, 11 Jul 2015 07:33:01 +0100",
<,QUIT,
>,221 2.0.0 Service closing transmission channel,
-,Local
```

So it looks like the Exchange is terminatting the connection after stating that it is ready.

Fortunately the smart host does try to resend them and they are eventually delivered but not after 6 or 7 attempts however there is one client that is rejected with that message 100% of the time.

We have checked with our solutions provider (that control the firewall in front of the hosted virtual exchange) and all firewall settings appear to be correct.

I hope someone can shed some light on this issue.

Comment: It seems that your server sends `QUIT` command after seeing SMTP greeting message of MS Exchange.  Does your MS Exchange support `VRFY` command or rejects non existing recipients in reply to `RCPT TO`?

Comment: The VRFY command is disabled at our side. Is VRFY not a legacy command anyway? I didn't think it was good practice to have it on. Successful deliveries from the smart host do not use this command. We don't reject non existing users either but I don't think it would make a difference if it did as the email destinations are existing mailboxes.